# Create new dataframe from similar values in two columns from two data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes (dataframe A and B). Both dataframes include the columns 'Data' and 'About', but the other columns are different.

I would like to change dataframe A by deleting the rows which dataframe B does not have.

So, for example:

Dataframe A

```
A = {'Date': ["20-10-2020", "23-10-2020", "24-10-2020", "28-10-2020"], 
     'About': [Sandra, Peter, Mare, Bas], 'Score': [15, 20, 35, 21],     
     'Hours': [2, 4, 5, 1]}
```

Dataframe B

```
B = {'Date': ["20-10-2020", "26-10-2020", "24-10-2020", "28-10-2020"], 
     'About': [Sandra, Suzan, Koen, Bas], 
     'ASWR': [105, 170, 120, 101]]}
```

As you see both include Date and About, but the rest is different.

Now I would like to get this:

Dataframe A (output)

```
A = {'Date': ["20-10-2020", "28-10-2020"],
     'About': [Sandra, Bas],
     'Score': [15,21],
     'Hours': [2, 1]}
```

As you see the data from Peter and Mare is deleted because the Data and/or about value did not match with dataframe B

I tried the following code

```
df_A = df_A.loc[~((df_A['Date'].isin(df_B['Date'])))]
```

However, I could not do this for date and about at the same time.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> df_A.merge(df_B, on=["Date", "About"])
         Date   About  Score  Hours  ASWR
0  20-10-2020  Sandra     15      2   105
1  28-10-2020     Bas     21      1   101
```